# Populating listview with List<List<string>>

Tags: c#

I'm coding in C# andI have a listview control with few columns, and I'm wondering, how can I add items to it from `List<List<string>>`. I am able to add items with

```
var item3 = new ListViewItem(new[] { table[0][0], table[0][1], table[0][2], table[0][3], table[0][5], table[0][7], table[0][8] });
```

but that doesn't seem right to me, and neither it would work because the amount of Lists is random.

Comment: Have you tried `new ListViewItem(table[0].ToArray())` ?

Comment: yo0u probably need to ask yourself why are you storing a List of a List of strings? I am sure there is another way you could be using, perhaps a list of key value pairs or maybe a Dictionary or something like that. of course, we don't know your requirements here but only speculating. But if you insist on using your type of collection then you would need to use a foreach loop for both outer ad inner - again, depends what you are wanting to do with "item3". you can, as suggested use the ToArray() method to feed into the object.

Comment: @Mikkula `new ListViewItem(table[0].Where(x=>somecondition(x)).ToArray())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`List<T>.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) to convert the list into an array which you then pass to the constructor of [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f.aspx). As you are only interested in the first subitem of your table, you can just do it like this:

```
var item3 = new ListViewItem(table[0].ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to fill all the `List<List<string>>` into your `ListView`:

```
listView1.Items.AddRange(table.Select(list=>new ListViewItem(list.ToArray())))
               .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you mean like this ?

**sample data**

***item1***

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("item-1.1");
list1.Add("item-1.2");
```

***item2***

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("item-2.1");
list2.Add("item-2.2");
```

***allitem***

```
List<List<string>> listAll = new List<List<string>>();
listAll.Add(list1);
listAll.Add(list2);
```

---

**string value**

```
string sResult = string.Join(", ", from list in listAll from item in list select item);
```

**list value**

```
List<string> lResult = new List<string>(from list in listAll from item in list select item);
```

**binding**

```
lv.DataSource = lResult;
lv.DataBind();
```

**result**

> item-1.1 item-1.2 item-2.1 item-2.2